# $(this) in source of jquery autocomplete - why doesn't it work, but the workaround does?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I was having some trouble with the following code. $(this) appeared to be undefined.

```
$('.version-autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: '/ajax/versions.json?procedure_name=' + $(this).attr('procedure_name')
})
```

I found that this works, and I'm wondering why that is. Does anybody know?

```
$('.version-autocomplete').each(function(i, el) {      
    $(el).autocomplete({
        source : '/ajax/versions.json?procedure_name=' + $(el).attr('procedure_name')
    })  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second version, you're in an `each` callback, but in the first, `$(this)` is evaluated immediately and doesn't point to the element you want. You can also use `this` properly in the `each`, by the way:

```
$('.version-autocomplete').each(function() {      
    $(el).autocomplete({
        source: '/ajax/versions.json?procedure_name=' + $(this).attr('procedure_name')
    });
});
```